# Split files present in different Folders in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a folder that contain many folders and each folder contains one csv file. I want to split each file on the basis of CN into its own folder.This is the position of files:

```
home -> folder   -> f_5324 -> f_5324.csv
                 -> f_5674 -> f_5674.csv
                 -> f_8769 -> f_8769.csv and so on
```

I want to write a code that will take first folder(f_5324) read csv file then split that file and save in that folder(f_5324) then take second folder(f_5674) read csv file then split and save in that folder(f_5674) then will do the same with all folders.
This is my code in R :-

```
dir <- "/home/folder"
my_dirs <- list.dirs(dir, recursive = FALSE)

for(i in my_dirs){
    a <- list.files(path = i, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
    df <- read.csv(a)
    a0 <-  df[df$CN=="cn=0",]
    a1 <-  df[df$CN=="cn=1",]
    a3 <-  df[df$CN=="cn=3",]
    a4 <-  df[df$CN=="cn=4",]
    write.csv(a0,"cn0.csv")
    write.csv(a1,"cn1.csv")
    write.csv(a3,"cn3.csv")
    write.csv(a4,"cn4.csv")
}
```

I am trying hard but it's not working properly it splits the file but creates one file for cn0,cn1,cn3,cn4 and overwrite all results. please tell me how to pass path to each folder and get separate result for all csv file in there own folder.
Help will appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -

```
dir <- "/home/folder"
my_dirs <- list.dirs(dir, recursive = FALSE)

for(i in my_dirs){
  a <- list.files(path = i, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
  df <- read.csv(a)
  a0 <-  df[df$CN=="cn=0",]
  a1 <-  df[df$CN=="cn=1",]
  a3 <-  df[df$CN=="cn=3",]
  a4 <-  df[df$CN=="cn=4",]
  write.csv(a0,paste(i,"cn0.csv",sep="/"))
  write.csv(a1,paste(i,"cn1.csv",sep="/"))
  write.csv(a3,paste(i,"cn3.csv",sep="/"))
  write.csv(a4,paste(i,"cn4.csv",sep="/"))
}
```

**Explanation**

In your initial implementation, `write.csv(a0,"cn0.csv")` implies you are writing a csv file named `cn0.csv` to your present working directory.

Next time the loop comes, it is just overriding the existing file again and again.

To avoid this, you need to specify the directory correctly for each csv write, which has been done by modifying to `write.csv(a0,paste(i,"cn0.csv",sep="/"))`, which populates the correct target directory.